# Insert divs in top timelene view odoo 13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to place some buttons/div on top of a dashboard, but the view is not qweb and if I try to add a div it does not render it. How do I get it to add those buttons on top of that board?

[image: open image 1]

[image: open image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to open web development tools in your browser, and then try add div container manually. Then try to copy it in your odoo base.

if you want add a button, you can use [this](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/10_actions.html#howto-rdtraining-10-actions) official tutorial from docs

, or try to search in your project "<button" for examples

Comment: I already added a button before and/or after the timeline tag, but it throws an error. Error: The timeline view does not have the 'date_start' attribute defined.
    at Class.start (http://localhost:1998/web/content/4826-a7e52f4/web.assets_backend.js:4196:1533)
    at prototype.<computed> [as start] (http://localhost:1998/web/content/4809-dc03a37/web.assets_common.js:3861:488)
    at http://localhost:1998/web/content/4809-dc03a37/web.assets_common.js:4107:52
    at async Promise.all (index 1)

Comment: I also used xpath to add after top div but it doesn't render either